# What is the Node/Shard limit for MongoDB ona 64 bit machine?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

We are currently setting up a mongodb database for our enviroment. We are running into specific collections which will initially be more then 2gb of size.

Out deployment enviroment is a 64bit Ubuntu machine.

We are trying to find what is the limit of a sizes of a specific collection and shard for mongodb in a sharding enviroment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no limit to the size of a collection within MongoDB. The only limit would be the amount of disk space available to you. In the case of sharding, it would be the total amount of disk space available on all shards. And according to the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Limits#ShardingLimits-ScaleLimits), you can only have 1000 shards.

Comment: Tnx, for the answer. The problem we are facing is that we find multiple values all over for example a 1TB limit etc

Comment: Interesting. The docs are pretty clear there's no limit, but if you need more confirmation, you can always go over to the Google group. The 10gen team is really active there. http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/topics